# VBA to list number combinations sequentially in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to list the possible combinations of numbers 1 to 26 in columns A and B, in the following format:

```
    1 1
    1 2 
    1 3
    1 4
    ...
    1 25
    1 26
    2 1
    2 2
    2 3
    ...
etc
```

For Column A, I could have:

```
Range("A1:A26") = 1
Range("A27:A52") = 2
etc
```

But this seems long winded and there must be a better way of doing this.

I have found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/114097/filling-cells-with-sequential-numbers-in-an-excel-2003-macro) code as an answer to another question which gives

```
Range("A1")=-500
Range("A1").Select
Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
        Step:=1, Stop:=500, Trend:=False
```

as a way to list numbers sequentially but I would need to amend it to reach 26 and then start again from 1, all the way to the end of the list in Column A. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does order matter? In your example you have (1, 2) and (2,1) which are the same combination?

Comment: @AlexP order does matter as in my dataset [1,2] and [2,1] are different combinations. Its combinations of zones that traffic can go from and to, so going from 1 to 2 is different to going from 2 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these formulas and then drag down as far as you need (row 676):

`A1 =ROUNDUP(ROW()/26,0)`

`B1 =IF(MOD(ROW(),26)=0,26,MOD(ROW(),26))`

Comment: Thanks. I added `Range("A1:A676").Formula =` and then your formulae and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

A VBA solution as an alternative to the Excel formulas given in the previous reply. (Untested)

```
MyRow = 1 ' or wherever you want to start
MyCol = 1 ' or wherever you want to start
For A = 1 to 26
  For B = 1 to 26
    Cells(MyRow,MyCol).Value = A
    Cells(MyRow,MyCol+1).Value = B
    MyRow = MyRow + 1
  Next B
Next A
```

The advantage of this approach instead of the formula described above is that it is not dependent on where you place the data. It can also be adapted if you want (e.g.) combinations of 5 to 24, or even A is 1 to 26 and B is 1 to 10.

But, the formula described in the previous answer is also a cool way of doing it.

If you changed:

```
For A = 1 to 26
  For B = 1 to 26
```

to

```
For A = 1 to 26
  For B = A to 26
```

then this would be useful for a non-directional combination (e.g. if [1,2] is the same as [2,1]).